# Twilio how to solve Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig

Tags: java, android, twilio, sendmessage

I am trying to use Twilio site for send message.
When I run this code :

```
Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message message = 
com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber),
                    new PhoneNumber("+******"),
                    message1).create();
```

I face this error: 
`Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig`
[image: Error message]

I saw this solution but I don't know where should I put this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We do not recommend that you use the Twilio REST API directly from an Android application as it would be trivial for an attacker to decompile the application, retrieve your account sid and auth token and abuse your account.

My colleague Marcos wrote up a blog post on [how to send SMS messages from an Android application](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html) and I recommend you follow his advice.

Comment: Thanks,
You are right but I am asking about why it does not work?
Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm not an Android developer myself, so I'm not entirely sure. However, this library wasn't built to run on Android so may not include things that are expected in a regular Java environment. That may be the issue, so I'd still recommend following the blog post rather than carrying on down this track.

Comment: @HazemENG Did you manage to figure out the issue. Although I understand the recommendation above but did you solve the issue on the android side ?

Comment: No I didnot solve it.
But you can get rid of it if you send request from webservice not from Android.

Comment: @Hazem Did you find a way to implement it in android? I'm want to generate NTS Token (https://www.twilio.com/docs/stun-turn/api) and I'm facing the same error. Could you please help?